# Как сделать ввод N строчек по N чисел?

Tags: python

Записано N строчек по N чисел. Числа в строках разделены пробелами.

```
Пример:
0 0 0
1 1 1
0 0 0

0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для заранее известного n:

```
data = []
for y in xrange(0, n):
    row = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    assert len(row) == n
    data.append(row)
```

Или (без assert'а, но однострочник, Python 2.x):

```
data = [map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()) for _ in xrange(0, n)]
```

Для Python 3.x `map` возвращает не список, так что потребуется или обернуть `map` в `list` или, более универсально, записать чуть длиннее:

```
data = [[int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readline().split()] for _ in range(0, n)]
```

Для неизвестного n (определение по первой сточке):

```
data = []
n = None
while True:
    row = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    if n is None:
        n = len(row)
    assert len(row) == n
    data.append(row)
    if len(data) >= n:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = []
with open('file', 'r') as ff:
    for line in ff.readlines():
            numbers.append (list (map (int, line.split())))
```